# Computing descriptive statistics with MySQL without a GROUP BY statement

Tags: mysql, statistics

I have a table with three numbers in each record, a minimum, a maximum, and an observed value. I would like to estimate an interpolation that predicts the observed value given minimum and maximum values. To do this, I would like to calculate an average and a standard deviation for the slope and intercept for each record. My understanding is that the `STDDEV` and `AVG` functions apply only to queries that have a `GROUP BY` clause. Mine table doesn't have anything that I can group by, unless I do something stupid like group by whether the record id is odd or even. Is there a way to compute these kinds of descriptive statistics using MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to use `GROUP BY` to use `AVG` and `STDDEV` as the following example shows:

```
mysql> select * from test;
+------+------+----------+
| min  | max  | observed |
+------+------+----------+
|    1 |   10 |        2 |
|    2 |   20 |        4 |
+------+------+----------+


mysql> SELECT AVG(observed) FROM test;
+---------------+
| AVG(observed) |
+---------------+
|        3.0000 |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> SELECT STDDEV(observed) FROM test;
+------------------+
| STDDEV(observed) |
+------------------+
|           1.0000 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: My bad. I got confused by the documentation & the error message I got when I tried it. Should have been more careful.

Answer (score 0):

do you want to calculate the aggregates for all the records? put them into one group:

```
GROUP BY "1"
```